# core-js3 can't find core-js/client/shim.min.js

Tags: core-js

I have an example of application (Angular-AngularJS hybrid app) where may be necessary to use 
core-js/client/shim.min.js
But in current version core-js (version 3) we haven't such file.
What can I use instead on it?

I use it here (to bootstrap hybrid app):

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <base href="/">
    <script>
        System.import('/app');
    </script> -->
    <script src="/node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="/node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js"></script>
    <script src="/dist/ang_js_lib.js"></script>  
    <script src="/dist/ang_js_app.js"></script> 
    <script src="/dist/ang_app.js"></script>
    <script src="/systemjs.config.js"></script>
    <script>
        System.import('/');
    </script>
  </head>

  <!-- <body ng-app="mainApp" ng-strict-di> -->
  <body>
    <div id="message" ng-controller="MainCtrl as mainCtrl">
      {{ mainCtrl.message }}
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the package `core-js-bundle` instead of `core-js` and point in your index.html to the following:

`<script src="node_modules/core-js-bundle/index.js"></script>`
or
`<script src="node_modules/core-js-bundle/minified.js"></script>`